# Send constant number of http requests without waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hi guys I am trying to use a simple console application to send requests to service without out waiting. The goal is to send 100 requests per second without waiting for the response. My idea is to create and run 10 threads at a time, each thread will create a http client and send request. after threads created then wait for 100 ms, then create another 10 threads. The code looks like:

```
while (true)
{
     try
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
               Task.Factory.StartNew(SendRequest);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          // ignored
     }

     Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Each SendRequest method will print http status code the result to console after get the result from http request. But I found that this application will successfully print first 20 result, which means that threads has finished and destroyed. But after this, it will no longer print anything out, but the memory is increasing, which means that thread is kept creating but spinning. So, could you help answer:

1) why the thread is hanging after 20 requests finished, is it because of the connection limit at http client?

2) how to send constant requests per second without waiting by using code?

Comment: Are these requests to a single URL? A single host? Multiple hosts?

Comment: Try catch is useless, as the exception is stored in task itself

Answer (score 0):

May be off topic, but if you don't need to do this in C#, you can use apache benchmark to do this and test out. You can control concurrency, time and number of requests.

```
ab -c 10 -t 60 -n 6000 http://www.website.com/
```

If it has to be in C# .. then sorry and nevermind